# In GitHub, at what levels can review comments be made?

Tags: git, github

In GitHub, when code reviewer make review comments, I sometimes lose track of some comments, especially when the comments come from several repositories.

In order to show/list all the comments directed to me, what levels can comments be made?

- pull request level, i.e. for merging a branch to another branch, so when I click a pull request, I can find all the comments on that pull request?
- commit level, so when I click a commit, i can find all the comments on that commit?
- branch level, so when I click a branch, i can find all the comments on that branch?
- user account level, so when I click my account, I can find all the comments directed to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pull request, reviewers can post general comments on the PR issue or on individual lines in each commit. The later are visible in the PR, though, so you should just look there for all feedback. If any reviewer makes comments which are not visible there, then you should feel free to ignore them because the reviewer is not doing their job properly.